# Is extra sum of squares $SSR(X_p|X_1,...X_{p-1})$ in multiple regression always positive?

Tags: probability, statistics

An extra sum of squares $SSR(X_p|X_1,...X_{p-1})$, assuming that no pair of predictor variables are perfectly correlated, measures the marginal reduction in the error sum of squares. Eventually one can view an extra sum of squares as measuring the measuring the marginal increase in the regression sum of squares when one or several predictor variables are added to the regression model.

Assuming the number of observational data $n$ is lager than the number of predictor variables $p$.

Can I have a rigourous proof that $SSTO=\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2\geq SSR(X_p|X_1,...X_{p-1})\geq0$ ?

---

Applying LSE

$SSE(X_1,...,X_{p-1})=\sum(Y_i-b_0-b_1X_{1,i}-...-b_{p-1}X_{p-1,i})^2=\sum(Y_i-b_0-b_1X_{1,i}-...-b_{p-1}X_{p-1,i}-0\times X_{p,i})^2\geq\sum(Y_i-b_0'-b_1'X_{1,i}-...-b_{p-1}'X_{p-1,i}-b_p'X_{p,i})^2=SSE(X_1,...,X_{p-1},X_p)$

$SSR(X_p|X_1,...X_{p-1})=SSE(X_1,...,X_{p-1})-SSE(X_1,...,X_{p-1},X_p)\geq 0$

Proved.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\text{SSTO}=\text{SSR}+\text{SSE}\\\text{SSR}=\text{SSTO}-\text{SSE}$.

Also note that $\text{SSE}(X_1,...X_{p-1})\ge \text{SSE}(X_1,...X_p)~\text{form normal equation}\\SSR(X_1,...X_p)\ge SSR(X_1,...X_{p-1})$

So, $SSR(X_p|X_1,...X_{p-1})\ge 0$ is true.

**Edit:** Note $$\sum(Y_i-\hat \beta_0-\hat\beta_1x_{1i}-\cdots-\hat\beta_px_{pi})^2\le \sum(Y_i-\hat \beta_0'-\hat\beta_1'x_{1i}-\cdots-\hat\beta_{p-1}'x_{(p-1)i})^2$$ Since $\{\hat \beta_0, \hat \beta_1,\dots,\hat \beta_p\}$ are least square estimators.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand the question well. $SSR(X_p|X_1,...X_{p-1})$ is not sum of squares. It measures the difference, namely $SSR(X_p|X_1,...X_{p-1})=SSR(X_1,...X_p)-SSR(X_1,...,X_{p-1})$. I'm asking for proof that $SSR(X_1,...X_p)\geq SSR(X_1,...,X_{p-1})$

Comment: @ZhangTschao: i edit my answer. take a look.

Comment: We may or may not assume constant variance for the residual, but definitely we don't assume the residual is normal. Can you provide a detailed proof that $SSE(X_1,...,X_{p-1})\geq SSE(X_1,...,X_p)$ ? @Argha

Comment: @ZhangTschao: I don't assume that residual is normal. To get normal equation we don't need to assume that residual is normal. It comes by minimizing the error sum of squares.

Comment: Thanks very much if only you could provide a detailed proof that $SSE(X_1,...,X_{p-1})\geq SSE(X_1,...,X_p)$ @Argha

Comment: @ZhangTschao: See my post again.

Comment: but the estimators on the left hand side are different from those corresponding estimators on the right hand side. least square estimators require the sum on the left hand side to be the least among itself, not to be less than right hand side.

Comment: @ZhangTschao: It's typo. Reverse the inequality. I will edit.

Comment: I know it's typo. but the lest square estimator method doesn't require the sum on L.H.S. to be smaller than that on R.H.S.

Comment: The philosophy is error sum of squares is minimum when we use LSE. Since we use $\hat \beta_0=\hat \beta_0'$ in this way and $\hat \beta_p=0$. we get this inequality.